# Create Between Query using gorethink

Tags: go, rethinkdb

How to convert this rethinkdb query into gorethink query

`r.db("arkinventory").table("reportsdata").between(new Date("2012-08-13T23:32:49.923Z"), new Date("2013-08-13T23:32:49.923Z"), {index: "updated_at"})`

I tried

`.Filter(func(row r.Term) r.Term {
        return row.Between(r.Time(2014, 8, 12, 'Z'), r.Time(2014, 8, 12, 'Z'), r.BetweenOpts{Index: "updated_at"})
    }).Run(session)`

row.Date
row.ToEpochTime

But yet not able to get the result. Please help me formulate this query in gorethink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per dancannon's response on gitter channel https://gitter.im/dancannon/gorethink

We should use During instead of Between for Dates.

`Filter(func(row r.Term) r.Term {
    return row.Field("updated_at").During(r.Time(2014, 8, 12, 'Z'), r.Time(2014, 8, 12, 'Z'))
}).Run(session)`

Answer (score 1):

```
t := r.Table("yourTable")
t.Between(from, to,
    r.BetweenOpts{Index: "updated_at"}
).OrderBy(r.OrderByOpts{Index: r.Desc("updated_at")}).Run(dbs)
```

Here, `from` and `to` depends how you save these values i.e int64, string, time, etc. According to previous example `r.Time(args)` should work.

If nonexist, create index via:

```
t.IndexCreate("updated_at").Exec(dbs)
t.IndexWait().RunWrite(dbs)
```

Comment: The filter around Between was the error. How ever I have not yet been able to get the result. But no more errors in Query. Thanks

Comment: Also the 'Z' should  have been "Z"

Comment: Thanks for the help Ferhat, however Dancannon responded saying, We should be using During instead of Between.